# MySQL - Apply condition in UNION

Tags: mysql

I'm doing the following select:

```
(SELECT id, chave, 'L' as tipo, codigo, clienteID, dataSaida, dataChegada, veiculo, situacao FROM locacoes WHERE chave = '1111111111111' && situacao='C')
    UNION
(SELECT id, chave, 'C' as tipo, codigo, clienteID, dataIni as dataSaida, dataFim as dataChegada,veiculo, status as situacao FROM contratos WHERE chave = '1111111111111' && status='F' )
```

Result I have:

[image]

**Now I need to apply a condition to the result.**

```
WHERE dataSaida >= '2020-05-06 11:26:00' AND dataChegada <= '2020-05-06 11:26:00'
```

I tried to do it this way, but it doesn't work.

```
(SELECT id, chave, 'L' as tipo, codigo, clienteID, dataSaida, dataChegada, veiculo, situacao FROM locacoes WHERE chave = '1111111111111' && situacao='C')
    UNION
(SELECT id, chave, 'C' as tipo, codigo, clienteID, dataIni as dataSaida, dataFim as dataChegada,veiculo, status as situacao FROM contratos WHERE chave = '1111111111111' && status='F' )
WHERE dataSaida >= '2020-05-06 11:26:00' AND dataChegada <= '2020-05-06 11:26:00'
```

How should I do?

Thank you.

### ATTEMPTS

Attempt 2

```
(SELECT id, chave, 'L' as tipo, codigo, clienteID, dataSaida, dataChegada, veiculo, situacao FROM locacoes WHERE chave = '1111111111111' && situacao='C' && dataSaida >= '2020-05-06 11:26:00' AND dataChegada <= '2020-05-06 11:26:00')
        UNION
(SELECT id, chave, 'C' as tipo, codigo, clienteID, dataIni as dataSaida, dataFim as dataChegada, veiculo, status as situacao FROM contratos WHERE chave = '1111111111111' && status='F' && dataIni >= '2020-05-06 11:26:00' AND dataFim <= '2020-05-06 11:26:00')
```

Attempt 3

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT id, chave, 'L' as tipo, codigo, clienteID, dataSaida, dataChegada, veiculo, situacao FROM locacoes WHERE chave = '1111111111111' && situacao='C'
        UNION
    SELECT id, chave, 'C' as tipo, codigo, clienteID, dataIni as dataSaida, dataFim as dataChegada, veiculo, status as situacao FROM contratos WHERE chave = '1111111111111' && status='F' 
)
AS sub
WHERE sub.dataSaida >= '2020-05-06 11:26:00' AND sub.dataChegada <= '2020-05-06 11:26:00'
```

Comment: Put the condition into each separate subquery.

Comment: Your Where clause makes little sense they include all cars that where delivers before d '2020-05-06 11:26:00'  and leave at a date bigger '2020-05-06 11:26:00', it you have a good thughput ist should be every car

Comment: @nbk The intention of using WHERE is to know which record is within what I need.

Comment: please add the data like described in [mre] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query  it is hard to guess what exactly you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can gather all the result into a subquery and transform to a derived_table, and then apply the filter the derived table.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html

After that you should change the comparison operators, so you can say (imagine the api date is 3pm on wednesday), give me all the records when

the exitDate(dataSaida) is before <= wednesday 3pm, and the arrivalDate(dataChegada) is after >= wednesday 3pm.

That should be the fix , after getting results from derived table.

```
SELECT * FROM
    (    
        SELECT id, chave, 'L' as tipo, codigo, clienteID, dataSaida, dataChegada, veiculo, situacao FROM locacoes WHERE chave = '1111111111111' && situacao='C'
        UNION
        SELECT id, chave, 'C' as tipo, codigo, clienteID, dataIni as dataSaida, dataFim as dataChegada,veiculo, status as situacao FROM contratos WHERE chave = '1111111111111' && status='F'
    ) as derived_table
WHERE dataSaida <= '2020-05-06 11:26:00' AND dataChegada >= '2020-05-06 11:26:00'
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Osmar, I did as I said, but there was no result. As you can see in the image the date "2020-05-06 11:26:00" that I am using to compare is the first in the image.

Comment: I am seeing that dataSaida and dataChegada are both the same, maybe you should change the dataChegada to increase the range. Also you can go step by step, so you can remove only the filter and see what are the results.

Comment: The value of the date and time that will be passed is just one. It will be a value received from an API. So I pass this date and time, then I need to check which record is within that date, understand?

Comment: It would be basically this: dataSaida >= {date API time} <= dataChegada

Comment: no the times are ok, the ey are arrival and received times, so he wants all cars, that leaved after <'2020-05-06 11:26:00' and cars that where delivers before, but that should be all cars

Comment: I got it, so if you remove the WHERE condition the derived table gives you any information?

Comment: @OmarAlvarado Without WHERE, returns this data https://i.stack.imgur.com/FixUC.png

Comment: WHERE sub.dataSaida >= '2020-05-06 11:26:00' AND sub.dataChegada <= '2020-05-06 11:26:00'
That sentence makes no sense, it means that the exit date is the very same of arrival date, that means the car wasn't out in any moment, and there is no rows acomplishing the condition.

Comment: I think you should change the comparison operators to this WHERE dataSaida <= '2020-05-06 11:26:00' AND dataChegada >= '2020-05-06 11:26:00'

Comment: How is the correct form? Because via API I only get a date and I need to check which record is corresponding. I'm not looking for an exact date and time, but records that match the date informed by the API.

Comment: It's like if you say saida <= (before) wednesday and chegada >= (after) wednesda, it means the car went out before wednesday and went in after wednesday, so the car was out on wednesday

Comment: I will try to illustrate what I am doing. You have your car and share it with your relative, but everyone who takes the car notes the date and time, so far ok. Now when a ticket arrives at your address the ticket has the date and time, with that date and time you can know who was with the car. Understood?

Comment: Yes, let me try

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you

Comment: I made the change, but it doesn't return data. See image https://prnt.sc/vaa2t0

Comment: I am sorry, I changed the second date, I already edited to have the right date. PLease try again.

Comment: Thank you my friend!

Comment: Happy to help! :)